# Is using polymorphism a good way to store different datatypes under one container?

Tags: c++, class, memory

An example would be create a base class which has several derived classes which all have a different datatype associated to them. Int, double and an object of another class for example.

If each derived class has its own datatype would I be able to generically use the base class so that I can talk to all derived classes while only naming the base class.

My plan is to store the memory locations of the classes and initiate them and store them all under one custom container. (I am going to recreate a Map container to learn)

Once stored as a address would I need to specifically state the memory location amount or would the compiler know as the classes are derived.

Without using any third party tools.

Comment: You can use boost::any or boost::variant for that kind of thing.  I would if I were you, rather than making your own.  "variant" is the keyword you're looking for, btw.

Comment: Yes you can do this, as long as you're storing pointers in your container. Otherwise you run into the *slicing problem*.

Comment: @MarkRansom would I have to specifically state the size of the pointers or would the compiler making the sizes bigger so that no information is lost. Do you know of any documentation which may help me with this?

Comment: When you use `new` to create the pointer, it will use the proper amount of memory for the class type that you specify to `new`. You will also need a virtual destructor on the base class if you will be deleting the pointers without first casting them to the proper type.

Comment: Pointers are all the same size: exactly one address. What the pointer points at can be any size. Recommend a bit of playing with and learning about pointers before proceeding. If you have defined your destructors as `virtual`, the runtime will be able to figure out the sizes and delete correctly.

Comment: I'm not exactly clear on what you're trying to achieve. So let me just warn not to fall into the trap of trying to create your own entire type system on top of the one provided by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If you want to use polymorphism only to be able to store data in one container it's not good idea. As Robinson mentioned in comment boost can help you (`boost::any` and `boost::variant`). With upcoming c++17 standard you will have those at your disposal in `std` namespace: `std::any` and `std::variant` .

Comment: I am not wanting to use any third party librarys. If I wanted to do it without any additional librarys what would you suggest?

Comment: Well... I don't know why you don't want to use boost, but it's your choice :) . You could craft your own implementation of `any` . There should be some examples how to accomplish it on the net.

Answer (score 0):

Yes polymorphism could be an option, as long as you can setup an api common to all your objects. As mentioned by Mark, you should deal with pointers, or better smart pointers; objects size will be automatically managed this way.

The following code illustrates how you could implement a container for multiple types. The container (a vector) stores smart pointers, each pointing to an object dynamically allocated, and each having a constant size (whatever object pointed size is).

```
class Base {
    public:
    virtual ~Base() {}
    virtual void work(int) = 0;
};
class A : public Base {
    void work(int i) {std::cout << "A:" << i << std::endl; }
};
class B : public Base {
    void work(int i) {std::cout << "B:" << i << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>> db;
    db.push_back(std::make_shared<A>());
    db.push_back(std::make_shared<B>());
    db[0]->work(0);
    db[1]->work(1);
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
A:0
B:1
```